# vue-router и асинхронные действия

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Доброго времени суток.

Написал скрипт доступа на страницу:

```
import store from '@/store'

export default function (to, from, next) {
  if (store.getters.isAdmin) {
    next()
  } else {
    next('/?login=true')
  }
}
```

Авторизация на сайте работает через сессию, так вот при обновлении страницы или входу по прямой ссылке, он в любом случае выбрасывает на главную страницу, хотя при инициализации проекта выполняется

```
  async beforeCreate () {
    if (this.$session.exists()) {
      await this.$store.dispatch('registerSessionUser', this.$session.get('user'))
    }
  }
```

Но действия выполняются параллельно, из-за он не может понять что юзер уже авторизирован. Хотя на главной странице, уже все в порядке.

Вопрос: Как заставить дождаться выполнения диспатча? Или проверить авторизацию?

Навесив на хуки `beforeCreate` и `Create` а так же файл проверки авторизации консоль, обнаружил что router выполняется до их выполнения, как так?

консоль:

```
file AUTH
beforeCreate
Create
```

Comment: Попробуйте в beforCreate() написать `let result = await this.$store.dispatch('registerSessionUser', this.$session.get('user'))` , а в конце `return result`

Comment: Нет router обрабатывает до него, консоль дала `router beforeCreate` т.е. роутер уже сформирован, придумал другую систему авторизации, но вопрос еще открыт. Четыре дня понять не могу, почему так.

Comment: Информации мало. Сложно сказать почему так может быть.

Comment: Ну не суть, вопрос в том, почему vye-router билдится до всего проекта.

Comment: Так он и должен до проекта стартовать, разве нет?

Comment: Так вот у меня в нем проверка на авторизацию, как он может пройти если проект не загружен ))

Comment: А попробуйте не перед хуком async ставить, а внутри хука beforeCreate() напишите асинхронную функцию. Пробовали так?

Comment: Пробовал, все так же.

Comment: Ну тогда не знаю. Надо все видеть, чтоб разбираться. )